# How to copy a NSMutableArray in to another array?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I am trying to copy an array to another array my code is below

```
NSMutableArray firstArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSMutableArray secondArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[firstArray addObject:@"1"];
[firstArray addObject:@"2"];
[firstArray addObject:@"3"];
[firstArray addObject:@"4"];
[firstArray addObject:@"5"];

// have tried following ways

// 1
secondArray=[firstArray copy];

// 2
[secondArray addObjectsFromArray:firstArray];

//3
secondArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:firstArray];
```

It is working fine but the problem is that when modify the firstArray it reflects it changes in secondArray I don't want that.

Please tell which is the correct way

Comment: I find it hard to believe what you are saying. (1)secondArray = [firstArray copy] - the compiler should tell you off because the result isn't mutable. In neither case will changes in firstArray be reflected in secondArray. Did you actually run this code?

Comment: Yes I did run the code.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is, you create a "shallow" copy. What you want is a "deep" copy:

```
NSArray *deepCopyArray=[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:someArray copyItems:YES];
```

or

```
NSArray* trueDeepCopyArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:
      [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:oldArray]];
```

You can find more about this at [Copying Collections](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Collections/Articles/Copying.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010162-SW3) of Mac Developer Library.

Comment: This would only be an issue if you are storing mutable objects. `NSString` is immutable. You must also be sure that all objects in the array conform to `NSCopying` (option 1) or `NSCoding` (option 2) for this to work.